# scala build with intellij

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, sbt

I created a maven project using IntelliJ on Windows 7 Pro, in order to write then compile some scala.

I noticed that when I run my program using install maven goal from the maven interface, it perfectly works.

But when I go with Intellij build using Build menu + Build Project, some other compiler seems to build the project, and I get an sbt build error.

This means that Intellij default builder does not correspond the maven builder which appears in the right part of the screen !

My question is : how can I configure the builder used by (menu build + Build Project) so I can point to the maven builder of the project?

Comment: Please share the error stack trace that you get while using Build option. Also would be helpful to see you maven <build> configuration in pom.xml

Comment: If possible, share a link to an example project